# Any number of parameters in a controller?

Tags: symfony

I need to find a solution for the following problem:

After basic url (say "domain.org/elements") I need to have a hierarchical structure of elements following this basic url, and user if free, possibly infinitely, add another elements at any level, including element-containers, e.g. url for the example some containers and 1 element at the end of this hierarchy could look like these ones:

```
domain.org/elements/container-top/container-deeper/container-deeper2/element
domain.org/elements/container-top/container-deeper/container-deeper3/..../container-deeperN/element
```

The problem is: how to identify such routes in the Symfony2 controller, not using solutions like a Dynamic Controller (I don't want e.g. to save routes to DB)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could easily do something like this by tweaking the regular expression to use:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{parameters}", requirements={"parameters"="[^/]+(/[^/]+)*"})
 */
public function myAction($parameters)
{
    $parameters = explode('/', $parameters);
    // ...
}
```

The regular expression above reads like:

one or more non-forward slash character FOLLOWED BY zero or more (forward slash FOLLOWED BY one or more non-forward slash character)

Comment: This is definitely the way to go :) +1